# Alter text size on Home App

Tags: macos, ios, accessibility, homekit

Apple's Home app is difficult to use for me.

In all platforma macOS Venturea, IPadOS and IphoneOS it looks quite good except that I cannot read the information - like the temperatures as the text is too small. How do you increase the text size?

ALso on macOS I cannot read all the headings as they are white on very light grey. I uise Dark Mode for macOS,

I can use all the other Apple apps (e.g. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> so not a system issue. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> pops up the usual font panel but does nothing to the app.

This appears to be discriminated against people with less than perfect sight surely there must be a way around this.

Comment: Why can't you just change the text size for this particular app? Isn't this working for you?

Comment: If I could or knew how to do that I would not be asking the question. My question can be summed up as "How do I change the font in Home app"

Comment: So you want to change the *font*? Not the text size?

Comment: In macOS etc you change the font to change the text size. I want to change whatever to make it readable.

Comment: Have you tried pressing `cmd`+`+`?

Comment: Of course that was the first thing to do. It has no effect

Comment: Umm. I don't know how to do this on Mac (sorry). But I can give you an answer for iPad and iPhone. I'm preparing it right now, just tell me if you're interested.